# My app is not receiving whole data from device

Tags: android, buffer

In my application I need to receive data from custom device and save it in text file. Data is being sent through AP (socket). Connection is ok, creating file is ok , writing data is also ok. However I'm not receiving whole data. For example File is being closed in half way receiving and I'm loosing half of the data. What could be the problem ? Size of the buffer is ok.

here's my code :

```
private void synchData() {

        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERT_PORT);
                Log.e(TAG, "synchData0: ");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    if (serverSocket != null) {
                        socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                        new Thread(commThread).start();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "run: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;
        private BufferedReader input;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
            try {
                InputStream in = this.clientSocket.getInputStream();
                File root = new File("/sdcard/mente/" + user.getID() );
                if(!root.exists())
                    root.mkdirs();
                String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat(Helper.DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date()) + ".txt".replace(" ","_");
                file = new File(root,fileName);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                int count;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                while ((count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                    syncProgressDialog.show();

                    out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                    for (byte b : bytes) {
                        sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
                    }
                    Log.e(TAG, "CommunicationThread: " + sb.toString() );
                    if (sb.toString().contains("3C 65 6E 64 5F 72 61 77 3E 74 72 75 65 3C 2F 65 6E 64 5F 72 61 77 3E") && syncProgressDialog != null) {
                        syncProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2")));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            syncProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }
```

Comment: Did you get any IOException?

Comment: No, everything is fine.

Comment: `user.getID() `. Please elaborate.

Comment: `this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2")));` ??????? Please elaborate.

Comment: What do you mean ?